# How I send data to the database without refresh the page with click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I send data to the database without refresh the page with click button

**html:**

```
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">

<input name="a" type="text"/><br />
<input name="b" type="text"/><br />
<input name="c" type="text"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="go"/>

</form>

</body>
```

**jquery:**

```
<script>

var mm = {a:1000, b:1000, c:1000};
$.ajax({

url:"/index.php",

data:mm,
type:"POST",
success:function(data){
$(data).find("input[type=submit]").click();
return false;
}
});

</script>
```

But Page here refresh

How I send data to the database with click button without refresh the page by jquery ??!!

Comment: the ajax isn't refreshing the page, calling the click on the submit is.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap what you already have in a submit handler for the form:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var mm = {a:1000, b:1000, c:1000};
    $.ajax({
        url:"/index.php",
        data:mm,
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You sure? Looking at his code he's calling another submit on success, I think that is the one refreshing the page. does the e.preventDefault apply to that click too?

Comment: I didn't notice, and that's really weird because it was targeting a button on the returned data. Just removed it, doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: He doesn't have a click button. He has a form submit control, whose default action is to submit a form, so the e.preventDefault is correct. In the initial code, it looks like the form will submit on page load, and then as Rick pointed out, again on ajax() success.